# A pair of two digit numbers $ab = x$ and $cd = y$ is called romantic if $a + b = cd$ and $c + d = ab$. Are there even romantic numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

My work: It's simple to see that, with the definition given, two numbers are romantic if $s(x) + s(y) = x + y$, where $s$ is the function that sums the digits of the number (e.g $s(13) = 1 + 3 = 4$). Now, if $ 10 \leq x, y \leq 99$, then $s(x) + s(y) \leq 18 + 18 = 36$. So we only need to look for solutions in the set $A = \{10, 12, 14, 16,  \cdots, 26 \}$. For any $x, y \in A$, we have $20 \leq x + y \leq 52$, and so $2 \leq s(x) + s(y) \leq 18$. Therefore there are no $x, y \in A$ such that $x + y = s(x) + s(y)$. We conclude that there are no even romantic numbers.

Is this correct?

Comment: A quick computer search showed there are no such numbers under your conditions.

Comment: I don't see why you have $s(x)+s(y)\leq 7$. You could have $x=y=18\in A$, in which case $s(x)+s(y)=18$. You should just find what $a\in A$ maximizes $s(a)$ and find an upper bound for $s(x)+s(y)$.

Comment: @KevinLong I've edited my post. Is it correct now?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade I think you should emphasize that $a=18$ is the value in $A$ that gives the largest $s(a)$, and hence $s(a)\leq 9$, but you have the idea.